# UPDATE only a part of a string value in a column

Tags: sql-server

I am new to t-sql. I have a column which stores values as url's. I want to change the first part of the url's (string), and replace only this part with another url. For example, `[url//lsansps01/PMO/ITG0038 iSCOMBI Data Model Project]` to `[url2//lwazitest.lionsure.com/PMO/ITG0038 iSCOMBI Data Model Project]`

This is my update query:

```
UPDATE dbo.RowUpdates
SET ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef = REPLACE ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef, url//lsansps01/, url2//lwazitest.lionsure.com/PMO/ITG0038 iSCOMBI Data Model Project
FROM RowUpdates
WHERE ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef LIKE url
```

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE` uses `()` and not comma delimited parameters,

```
UPDATE dbo.RowUpdates
SET ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef = REPLACE(ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef, 'url//lsansps01/', 'url2//lwazitest.lionsure.com/PMO/ITG0038 iSCOMBI Data Model Project')
FROM RowUpdates
WHERE ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef LIKE url
```

another questionable part is `LIKE url` for it to work there should be `'%'+url+'%'` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at MSDN: [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186862.aspx)

from the article:
`REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )`

so you'd want to change your replace statement to (remember to use a quote (') around your strings):

```
UPDATE dbo.RowUpdates
SET ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef = 
    REPLACE(ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef, 'url//lsansps01/', 'url2//lwazitest.lionsure.com/PMO/ITG0038 iSCOMBI Data Model Project')
FROM RowUpdates
WHERE ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef LIKE url
```

It's also worth looking at the list of [String Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181984.aspx) you get in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

`Replace()` function will not give your expected results if *@OldUrl* text is found in the middle of the *ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef*.

If you want to replace only the front bit, use `RIGHT()` (or `SUBSTRING()`) function after filtering them out with `LEFT()` function.

```
DECLARE @OldUrl VARCHAR(500) = 'YourOdlUrl',
        @NewUrl VARCHAR(500) = 'YourNewUrl'

UPDATE dbo.RowUpdates
SET ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef = @NewUrl + 
      RIGHT(ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef,  LEN(ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef) - LEN(@OldUrl ))
WHERE LEFT(ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef, LEN(@OldUrl )) = @OldUrl
```